# Submit Button does not work in every browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form , There's a button called "submit" (form3) where when it's clicked the stuff that was entered in the form should be sent to the database or something else . Although when I click "Submit" nothing happens : 
===> see form :

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // it's use Firefox.... it's set UTF-8 character setting

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Author: Salhi Fadhel -->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8 no-js" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9 no-js" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <!-- start: HEAD -->
 <head>
  <title>RefactorErl</title>
  <!-- start: META -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta content="" name="description" />
  <meta content="" name="author" />
  <!-- end: META -->
  <!-- start: MAIN CSS -->
  <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main-responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/iCheck/skins/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme_light.css" id="skin_color">
  <!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->
  <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
 </head>
 <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/iCheck/jquery.icheck.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
  <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
  <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Main.init();
    Login.init();
   });
  </script>
 
 
 
 <!-- end: HEAD -->
 <!-- start: BODY -->
 <body class="login example2">
  <div class="main-login col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
   <div class="logo" color="red">RefactorErl
   </div>
   <!-- start: LOGIN BOX -->
   <div class="box-login">
    <h3>Sign in to your account</h3>
    <p>
     Please enter your name and password to log in.
     
    </p>
    <form class="form-login" id="form1" method="post" action="">
     <div class="errorHandler alert alert-danger no-display">
      <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> You have some form errors. Please check below.
     </div>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
       <span class="input-icon">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username or Email">
        <i class="icon-user"></i> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-actions">
       <span class="input-icon">
        <input type="password" class="form-control password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        <a class="forgot" href="#">
         I forgot my password
        </a> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right" name="login" id="login">
        Login <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="new-account">
       Don't have an account yet?
       <a href="#" class="register">
        Create an account
       </a>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>
   <!-- end: LOGIN BOX -->
   <!-- start: FORGOT BOX -->
   <div class="box-forgot">
    <h3>Forget Password?</h3>
    <p>
     Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.
    </p>
    <form class="form-forgot" id="form2" method="post" action="">
     <div class="errorHandler alert alert-danger no-display">
      <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> You have some form errors. Please check below.
     </div>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
       <span class="input-icon">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
       <button class="btn btn-light-grey go-back">
        <i class="icon-circle-arrow-left"></i> Back
       </button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right">
        Submit <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
       </button>
       
      </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>
   <!-- end: FORGOT BOX -->
   <!-- start: REGISTER BOX -->
   <div class="box-register">
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <p>
     Enter your personal details below:
    </p>
    <form class="form-register" id="form3" method="post" >
    
     <div class="errorHandler alert alert-danger no-display">
      <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> You have some form errors. Please check below.
     </div>
     <div class="successHandler alert alert-success no-display">
      <i class="icon-ok"></i> Your form validation is successful!
     </div>
     <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City">
      </div>

      <p>
       Enter your account details below:
      </p>
      <div class="form-group">
       <span class="input-icon">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <span class="input-icon">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <i class="icon-lock"></i> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <span class="input-icon">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_again" placeholder="Password Again">
        <i class="icon-lock"></i> </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
       <button class="btn btn-light-grey go-back">
        <i class="icon-circle-arrow-left"></i> Back
       </button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right" id="submit" >
        Submit <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>
   <!-- end: REGISTER BOX -->
   <!-- start: COPYRIGHT -->
   <div class="copyright">
    &copy; <?php echo date("Y")?> ELTE IK</i>
   </div>
   <!-- end: COPYRIGHT -->
  </div>
  
 </body>
 <!-- end: BODY -->
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{



 echo "<script>alert(\"Just a test .\");</script>";



 
}

?>
```

Comment: see the content of the form "form3": <form class="form-register" id="form3" method="post" >

Comment: only form3 not working @salhi ?

Comment: So onclick what do you expect?

Comment: @Nana and form2 but form1 is working correctly i spent more then 3 days on it

Comment: Your form needs an `action` attribute to identify what url the form should submit to.

Comment: the same url, its index.php and not working too

Comment: @SalhiFadhel : Update your latest code in question.

Comment: the button : <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right" name="simple" >Submit <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i></button> and the php code :                                                                              <?php
if (isset($_POST['simple']))
{
 echo "<script>alert(\"hello.\");</script>";
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `name='login'` in each submit button of each `<form></form>`

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right" name="login" id="login">
        Login <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right" name='login'>
    Submit <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-right" id="submit" name='login' >
    Submit <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
```

And, it worked for me for all 3 forms.

Success Screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: i did the same but nor working, the web interface is not the same as mine

Comment: but when i remove the import js and css ... it works

Comment: the problem is in this import :                                                                           <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>   , it controls my forms , what i should do in this case?